# Strong convergence of probability measures implies absolute continuity?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose that $(\mu_n)_n$ is a sequence of probability measure for which $\lim_n\langle\phi,\mu_n\rangle=\langle\phi,\mu\rangle$ where $\mu$ is a probability measure and $\phi$ is any bounded, real valued, measurable function. I want to show that if $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2^{-n}\mu_n(A)=0$ then $\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: What is the link between $A$ and $\phi$?

Comment: The $\mu_n$ as well as $\mu$ are Borel probability measures on some measurable space $(B,\mathcal{B})$ and $A\subset B$. $\phi$ is a bounded real valued (and so, obviously, measurable) function defined over all of $B$.

Comment: Perhaps you want a similar hypothesis on all bounded and real valued $\phi$? Or continuous $\phi$?

Also, being bounded and real valued does not imply measurability.

Comment: Oh sorry you're right. Assume that $\phi$ is measurable. I don't want to assume continuity of $\phi$. What else do you think must be assumed?

Comment: How do you define e.g. $\langle \phi,\mu\rangle$? I am not sure what it means to take the inner product of a random variable and a probability measure.

Comment: $\langle\phi,\mu\rangle = \int\phi d\mu$. There is no need to interpret $\phi$ as a random variable as $\phi$ could be $\mathbf{1}_A$ for instance and in which case $\langle\phi,\mu\rangle =\mu(A)$

Comment: If you have the convergence just **for one** $\phi$, this tells you almost nothing, e.g. for $\phi =0$. I strongly suspect you want to assume convergence for a certain class of $\phi$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures  In there it is $\forall \phi$ that are characteristic functions.

Comment: My question assumes that $\phi$ is a member of the class of bounded real valued measurable functions

Comment: I don't see anything in the article implying the result I want to prove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, this seems pretty straightforward.  Since all the $\mu_n$ are probability measures, in particular we have $\mu_n(B) \ge 0$ for every $B$.  So if $A$ is a measurable set such that $\sum 2^{-n} \mu_n(A) = 0$ then we must have $\mu_n(A) = 0$ for every $n$.  Now applying your convergence statement with the indicator function $\phi = 1_A$, we have
$$\mu(A) = \langle 1_A, \mu \rangle = \lim \langle 1_A, \mu_n \rangle = \lim \mu_n(A) = \lim 0 = 0.$$

Comment: Yes that works. Does the converse implication hold? Namely, $\mu(A)=0\implies\sum_n2^{-n}\mu_n(A)=0$?

Comment: @Albert: No, certainly not.  Consider a space with two points $a,b$.  $\mu_n$ puts mass $1/n$ on $a$ and mass $1-1/n$ on $b$, and $\mu$ puts mass 0 on $a$ and mass $1$ on $b$.  Then taking $A = \{a\}$, clearly $\sum_n 2^{-n} \mu_n(A) > 0$ but $\mu(A)=0$.